# how to pass section numbers to python in pythontex?

Tags: pythontex

I am writing out some parameters to JSON files using pythontex,
but would like to add context information in form of section numbers (for example \thesection or \thesubsubsection, perhaps also the page number or other counters).

Is there a straightforward way to pass the values of the section counters to Python?

- Josef

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways this could be done. Here's one approach. For another approach, see `\setpythontexcontext` in the pythontex documentation.

The pythontex commands like `\pyc` are designed to send code verbatim to Python. The trick here is to fully expand `\thesection` before storing it in a Python variable.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pythontex}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\sectopy}{%
  \edef\sectopy@val{\thesection}%
  \expandafter\sectopy@i\expandafter{\sectopy@val}}
\def\sectopy@i#1{\pyc{section = #1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Section}

\sectopy

The section is: \py{section}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't see how \setpythontexcontext can be used for this purpose, since \setpythontexcontext can only be used in the preamble.

Comment: @Josef `\setpythontexcontext` is used in the preamble to define a set of contextual data that is always available and up to date. So if you defined it to contain `section=\thesection`, then within Python code `pytex.context.section` would always contain the current section number.